# Function template is not a plain function

Tags: c++, templates

Why does the following code give us compile error:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int i = 0;

struct A
{
    void * operator new [] (size_t t)
    {
        cout << "allocation" << endl;
        return ::operator new[](t);
    }

    template <class T>
    void operator delete [] (void *p, size_t)
    {
        cout << "deallocation" << endl;
        return ::operator delete[](p);
    }
};

int main() 
{
    A *a = new A[10];
    delete [] a;//No suitable deallocation function
}
```

[demo](http://ideone.com/x6I0Bd)

I thought that `function template` is just a family function matched an appropriate template. This implies that non-placement function must be found in a struct definition.

Answer (score 1):

Your operator `delete[]` takes a `void*`, but has a template parameter `T` which is not used as a parameter type in the function signature, so the compiler can't resolve the function call.

You want:

```
void operator delete [] (void *p, size_t);
```

Comment: What do you mean as cannot resolve a function call? How does compiler resolve the function call?